I am unable to display EJS content with Google Maps polylines in a PDF using Puppeteer
I am trying to display a Google Map connecting the source and destination using a polyline, and convert that map to a PDF. I am using Puppeteer to convert EJS code to PDF. My map is loading, but it is not showing the polyline and markers.
I am sharing my code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Polyline with Markers</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 700px;">

    </div>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&loading=async&callback=initMap"> </script>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                { zoom: 8, center: { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 } });
            const polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [{ lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 },
                { lat: 37.7849, lng: -122.4294 },
                { lat: 37.7949, lng: -122.4394 },
                ],
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
            });
            const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            bounds.extend({ lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 });
            bounds.extend({ lat: 37.7949, lng: -122.4394 });
            map.fitBounds(bounds); polyline.setMap(map);
            const marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 }, map, title: "Start Point", }); const marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: { lat: 37.7949, lng: -122.4394 }, map, title: "End Point", });
        }
         window.onload = initMap 
    </script>
</body>

</html>

const samplePath = path.join('src', 'templates', 'views', 'sample.ejs') 
const template = fs.readFileSync(samplePath, 'utf-8') 
const content = ejs.render(template) 
const browser = await puppeteer.launch() 
const page = await browser.newPage() 
await page.setContent(content, { waitUntil: 'load' }) 
const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4',printBackground: true }) 
fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', pdfBuffer)


This is a bit tough to repro without a key, but does adding a few-second timeout before the PDF call work? If so, you can then try to tighten the predicate by listening for a script load or a more specific page state. EJS seems irrelevant here since there doesn't appear to be any interpolation.
